# NFC tag appending from Android

Tags: java, android, tags, nfc, ndef

I would like to know how to append some text to an NFC tag on Android. I know that `writeNdefMessage` can overwrite the the whole message on the tag but I did not find any method to append data to it. However, I would prefer to append it.

Comment: Why not extract the current message in the tag, add it to your new message, and then `writeNdefMessage(newString)`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We try to encourage posters here to do some solid research before asking, and then to show what they have tried. Is there anything you've found that you can show readers what you're starting with? It can often help show what you're trying to achieve, and may encourage more people to help you.

Comment: @MatterCat that's the plan but i would like to know is there any faster way which can just append to the tag.

Comment: @halfer thanks for your advice. I am new to stackoverflow and quite not use to it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stick to high-level (tag platform independent) access to NFC tags through the `Ndef` class, then you can only overwrite the whole NDEF message using `writeNdefMessage()`.

Android also permits you to directly send low-level commands to NFC tags (e.g. to issue a read/write command). You could use such commands to append data to a free memory area on the tag. However, how you would do this heavily depends to the tag platform that you use.

Comment: That heavily depends on your tag platform. There's no one-fits-all example for this.